# How to Create Chart in Excel using Apache POI in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create excel chart using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354092/create-excel-chart-using-apache-poi)

My project requires Chart to be created in Excel. How can I create Chart using Apache POI??

please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create charts using Apache POI. What you can do is to create an excel template and create the graph and bind the data.
[Limitaitons in POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Answer (score 1):

See the [POI SpreadSheet Limitations page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) - adding charts is not yet supported.

There's the possibility for a GSOC student to work on adding more chart support to POI this summer, if accepted, but for the mean time you can't.

The workaround for now is to load up excel, create named ranges for each series required, then create the chart to look as you want. Save this as a template file. As needed, open the template in POI, write in your data, then update the named range to refer to the new data. When you open in Excel, you'll then see the new data in the chart

Comment: thax for replay @Gagravarr:  i know this thing but any another way to create chart in excel using JAVA code ??????????????

Comment: Join the project and help out with adding the functionality? More volunteers are always welcome!

Comment: Thax for the Help i got solution.................