# create a pie chart in an excel file

Tags: java, sql, xls

I have created a csv file,

and display data from database into that file,

how can I add a pie chart to that file,

this is the code which I made:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/MY TOSHIBA/Desktop/chart.CSV");
Writer output =null;
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ 127.0.0.1:1521:XE","username","password");
String sql="select * from table";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
String teller =rs.getString("name");
String flag=rs.getString("flag");
output.write(teller+flag+"\n");
}
output.close();
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org)

Comment: so you want to have a graphic chart in the text file?

Comment: [ASCII Art?](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asciiart/)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't create charts in Text files.

If your question is about creating charts in excel using Java, you have to use ApachePOI. It will not create charts from the scratch, but it can link a chart from somewhere else to your excel file.

[Create excel chart using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354092/create-excel-chart-using-apache-poi)

However, I found the following in google, which seems like something, which is capable of doing what you are asking for

http://www.smartxls.com/java/drawings-charts.htm#vdrawings-charts-chart

Comment: The OP asked about creating charts in CSV files, not Excel (XLS / XLSX) files.

Comment: @RinMinase: Then you can tell him how to make charts in CSV files. I am also very interested to hear that.

Comment: Hahahaha. ASCII Art? :)

Comment: @Then convert it into CSV.